# Get Current user Login In Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

this my laravel Task Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\task;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
 
    public function getTask()
    {
        $userid=  Auth::user()->id;
        $response = task::where('id_karyawan',$userid)->get();
        return response()->json($response,200);
    }
  
}
```

but i get this error when i try it in postman. please help me to clear this error thanks

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file C:\Users\Lenovo\BackendBSIMonitoring\app\Http\Controllers\TaskController.php on line 37
```

Comment: Clearly there appears to be no authenticated user.

Comment: This indicates that there is no user authenticated. See you routes if this routes indicates the usage of the auth middleware 

Comment: You also need to send your auth token in Postman - it doesn't read your authentication from browser. It's like logging in a page from Chrome and expecting to be logged in in Firefox too

Comment: you need to use passport authentication, then it will be accessible, you need to learn more about Laravel and APIs : )

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check

**First** : Check if there is any user logged in currently

*If  user is not authenticated then `Auth::user()` will not work.*

**Second** : Check if you have used `Auth` Middleware in routes and while performing login

**Documentation** :

Routes : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Authenticate users : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Check if current user is authenticated or not : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated

Comment: Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
all route put in this middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

To get id of the user authenticated you can use

```
Auth::id()
```

or use helper function

```
auth()->id()
```